# django edit user and userprofile object

Tags: django

so i'm making a generic "accounts" page in django. I've used the django-registration plugin, and currently have a (djang-standard) User object, as well as a UserProfile and UserProfileForm object.

This is a question of style, or best-practices, i suppose. Is what i'm planning "right" or is there a "better/recommended/standard way" to do this?

What i'm planning on doing is creating the UserProfile from the request.user ie:

```
form = UserProfileForm(instance=User)
```

(and sending that form to the view), and in the UserProfileForm:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            self.user = kwargs['instance']
```

where my UserProfile is pretty much like so:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0) #how is the user going with scores?
```

and where User is of the `django.contrib.auth.models` variety.

Ok! The handling of the editing and saving will either be done via the `mixin` django stuff or, more likely because i haven't read up on mixins my own user-defined view that handles post and gets. But ignoring that - because i'm sure i should be using the mixins - is the above "right?" or are there suggestions?

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [user profiles on the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), the basics are listed there. You should also take a look at [using a form in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view).

Some specific feedback:

- You got the UserProfile model right, but you have to create an instance of one every time a new user is added (either through the admin interface or programmatically in one of your views). You do this by registering to the User `post_save` signal:

  ```
  def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      if created:
          UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
  post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
  ```
- You should init the ModelForm with an instance of the `UserProfile`, not `User`. You can always get the current user profile with `request.user.get_profile()` (if you define  `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in settings.py). Your view might look something like this:

  ```
  def editprofile(request):
      user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user_profile)
          if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')
      else:
          form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
      # ...
  ```
- No need for the **init** override in your ModelForm. You will be calling it with a UserProfile instance, anyway. If you want to create a new user, just call the User constructor:

  ```
  user = User()
  user.save()
  form = UserProfileForm(instance = user.get_profile())
  # ...
  ```

Comment: FYI as of today, AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE and get_profile has been deprecated